# XML grouping of based on child nodes dependency

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I tried the for-each-group loop but doesn't do the trick for me. Basically I have the following xml:

```
<Root>
    <Row>
        <CODE>A001</CODE>
        <LANG>EN</LANG>
        <DESCR>Car</DESCR>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <CODE>A001</CODE>
        <LANG>FR</LANG>
        <DESCR>Voiture</DESCR>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <CODE>A001</CODE>
        <LANG>NL</LANG>
        <DESCR>Auto</DESCR>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <CODE>A002</CODE>
        <LANG>EN</LANG>
        <DESCR>Bicycle</DESCR>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <CODE>A002</CODE>
        <LANG>FR</LANG>
        <DESCR>Velo</DESCR>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <CODE>A002</CODE>
        <LANG>NL</LANG>
        <DESCR>Fiets</DESCR>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

And I want to get the following output:

```html
<Root>
 <Row>
  <CODE>A001</CODE>
  <DESCR Lang="EN">Car</DESCR>
  <DESCR Lang="FR">Voiture</DESCR>
  <DESCR Lang="NL">Auto</DESCR>
 </Row>
 <Row>
  <CODE>A002</CODE>
  <DESCR Lang="EN">Bicycle</DESCR>
  <DESCR Lang="FR">Velo</DESCR>
  <DESCR Lang="NL">Fiets</DESCR>
 </Row>
</Root>
```

Appreciate the help in the way to transform this. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code that you have written so far for the transform please?

Comment: Like Peter Bailey said, please add the XSLT to your question. Also, what does "doesn't do the trick for me" mean? Did you not get the output you want? Did you get an error? (Is it possible you're not using a 2.0 processor and should really be using XSLT 1.0?)

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged as XSLT 2.0, here is an XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Root">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Root/Row" group-by="CODE">
                <xsl:element name="Row">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="CODE"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:element name="DESCR">
                            <xsl:attribute name = "Lang">
                                <xsl:value-of select="LANG"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="DESCR"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Produces the required output:

```
<Root>
   <Row>
      <CODE>A001</CODE>
      <DESCR Lang="EN">Car</DESCR>
      <DESCR Lang="FR">Voiture</DESCR>
      <DESCR Lang="NL">Auto</DESCR>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <CODE>A002</CODE>
      <DESCR Lang="EN">Bicycle</DESCR>
      <DESCR Lang="FR">Velo</DESCR>
      <DESCR Lang="NL">Fiets</DESCR>
   </Row>
</Root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

Use Muenchian grouping to group together `Row` with same value of `<CODE>` node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="codes" match="Root/Row" use="CODE"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Root">
            <xsl:for-each select="Root/Row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('codes',CODE)[1])]">
                <xsl:element name="Row">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="CODE"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('codes',CODE)">
                        <xsl:element name="DESCR">
                            <xsl:attribute name = "Lang">
                                <xsl:value-of select="LANG"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="DESCR"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: The grouping suggestion is fine but I wonder why you use `<xsl:element name="Root">` where a literal `<Root>` suffices.

Comment: Just to be consistent. Is there a significant performance overhead involved while using the <xsl:element> vs <Root> ? My guess is there should be, as the processor needs to translate the element tag to the Root tag. If yes, is it significant?

Comment: I think performance depends on the processor, personally I just think that using `xsl:element` instead of a literal result element is unnecessarily verbose and complicated, if you don't need to compute any part of the name or namespace of a result element then a literal result element suffices.